# how to do operations with elements of different datasets in R

Tags: r

i'm trying to create a dataset multiplying and adding elements of 3 different datasets:

```
a<-data.frame(1:2,2:1)  
b<-data.frame(3:4,4:3)  
c<-data.frame(10:11)
```

the dataframe i'm creating should have the same dimension as `a` and each elemnt should be calculated like this

`d[i,j]=a[i,j]/(c[i,1]-b[i,j])`

using a `for` should allow me to do this but when dealing with datasets of over a million rows it becomes somewhat slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use matrices and vectors:

```
amat <- matrix(c(1:2,2:1),2)
bmat <- matrix(c(3:4,4:3),2)
cvec <- 10:11

amat / ( cvec-bmat )

#           [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 0.1428571 0.3333333
# [2,] 0.2857143 0.1250000
```

Or, if your computation isn't as simple as the OP's example, loop over columns:

```
d   <- data.frame(matrix(,2,2))
d[] <- Map( function(aj, bj, cj) aj / (bj - cj), a, b, c )

#           X1         X2
# 1 -0.1428571 -0.3333333
# 2 -0.2857143 -0.1250000
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty much straightforward:

```
d <- a/(c[,1] - b)
```